# Using MySQL by Java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm coding some database transactions by using java. I'm sending a query using java. I think it has no problem with it. And if I send the query at prompt, it is working.

This method is updating book quantity.

```
 private static void updateBquantity(int bqt, String bname) {
    Connection con = makeConnection();
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        System.out.println(bqt + " " +bname);
        //this part is making problem
        stmt.executeUpdate("update books set bookquantity = bookquantity -" + bqt + "where bookname = '" + bname + "';");
        System.out.println("<book quantity updated>");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }

    stmt.executeUpdate("update books set bookquantity = bookquantity -" + bqt + "where 도서이름 = '" + bname + "';");
```

This part is making problem.

Other queries using this form is working.

The compiler says :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'bookname = 'Davinci Code'' at line 1

Help me.

Comment: spaces, backticks, all that jazz

Comment: It's a **query** - not a "querry" - one "r" is QUITE enough !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused with `bookname = 'Davinci Code`, where is bookname in your query? No matter what, in this query, you missed a blank before `where`, try this:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("update books set bookquantity = bookquantity -" + bqt + " where 도서이름 = '" + bname + "';");
```

Comment: Don't suggest doing it like this, it is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. @Kenny you should look into using prepared statements with parameter bindings to properly execute your query.